# php Laravel - given a certain argument, call different function

Tags: php, laravel

I am building a simple calendar with recurring events.

**CalendarEvent.php**

```
id
start_date
```

**CalendarRecurringPattern.php**

```
parent_id
pattern_type // daily, weekly, monthly, yearly ...
```

Using `pattern_type` i build each following occurrence starting from `start_date`, using a recursive function and `Carbon::class`. What bugs me is the function `getNextOccurrence()`, I'd like to refactor the if/else block because it's not very clean. Here it is:

```
use \Carbon\Carbon;
....

public function getNextOccurrence(Carbon $startDate) {

    $pattern_type = $this->getPatternType() // daily, weekly...

    if ($pattern_type == 'daily') {
        $startDate->addDay();
    } else if ($pattern_type == 'weekly') {
        $startDate->addWeek();
    } else if ($pattern_type == 'monthly') {
        $startDate->addMonth();
    } else if ($pattern_type == 'yearly') {
        $startDate->addYear();
    }

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: the commonplace suggestion would be to use `switch`,  but honestly I don't see what's wrong with a lot of nested if statements. Once I was eager to refactor this kind of code, but now I learned to value its verbosity and clean meaning, so I wouldn't change it into something more "elegant" but less readable

Comment: Thanks. I'm still growing as a developer and I'm doing my best to avoid bad habits. Recently I have been reading a lot about unit testing, a field in which I have no experience, and that function seemed not very clean from a testing perspective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't personally see a problem with the way its currently structured as there aren't that many options, but you could do it a couple of other ways;

### Option 1

Array function name mapping (hacky name I just came up with), you could do the following;

```
$functionMap = [
    "daily" => "addDay",
    "weekly" => "addWeek",
    "monthly" => "addMonth",
    "yearly" => "addYear"
];

if(!isset($functionMap[$pattern_type])){
    throw new \Exception("Can't find patern type $pattern_type", 1);
}

$startDate->$functionMap[$pattern_type]();
```

This might be seen as a sin by the PHP community but it works none the less

### Option 2

You could use a switch which probably isn't a sin by the community.

```
switch ($pattern_type) {
    case "daily":
        // Do the daily task
        break;
    case "weekly":
        // Do the weekly task
        break;
    case "monthly":
        // Do the monthly task
        break;
    case "yearly":
        // Do the yearly task
        break;
    default: 
        throw new \Exception("Can't find pattern type $pattern_type", 1);
}
```

### Conclusion

I would add some exception / error that can be picked up if a non matched  pattern_type is passed.

**I would also convert the "magic strings" E.G "daily" to constants in case you need to re-use, change or update them in the future!**

In terms of line count;

- your way 10 lines of code
- option 1  11 lines of code
- option 2  15 lines of code

The switch & if statements may have some advantages when doing code analysis aswel where the expected required input values can be picked up.

Comment: Thanks for this. 
I'm wondering, why should the option n.1 be seen as a sin by the community? 
I find myself using the same concept many times with javascript.

Comment: For example unit testing, unit testing would show this code as 100% tested even if you only tested one $pattern_type because there is only one path the code can take