# Formatting Credit card names from API response

Tags: php, strings

I have an API that returns the brand of a credit card. I want to make them look nice for my user (e.g. correct case and spacing). The possible options are `amex`, `diners`, `discover`, `jcb`, `mastercard`, `unionpay`, `visa`, or `unknown`. Here's how I am currently doing it:

```
if ($x == "jcb") {
    $x = strtoupper($x); 
} elseif ($x == "amex"){
    $x = "American Express";
} elseif ($x == "diners"){
    $x = "Diners Club";
} elseif ($x == "unionpay"){
    $x = "UnionPay";
} else {
    $x = ucfirst($x); 
}
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Related: [PHP code that chooses between multiple HTML banners](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/272263/141885) and [Optimization of a Laravel controller that passes data and views](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/272192/141885) and [Custom Block with ACF in WordPress](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/269492/141885) and [php Laravel - given a certain argument, call different function](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/196886/141885)

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ at what point does CodeReview consider the possibility of closing duplicates? Ever?

Comment: @mickmackusa see https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3821/120114

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ okay, well, this looks like one of those questions where the answer is "use this general technique".  They are all seeking to replace a battery of if conditions.  If older content is not used to close new, redundant content, then CR will be no better than archaic forums that contain "dead wood" content that is not maintained/scrutinized/modernized.

Comment: @Mast by rolling back my edit, you make it harder for people to find this page as a duplicate.  The "credit card names" and "API" keywords are not at all relevant to this review.

Comment: @mickmackusa "battery of conditions" while only a single variable is being checked for only a handful of conditions is not more descriptive. The current title is in line with Code Review standard, to describe what the code does. Conditions and strings are part of most of the questions here. Duplicate finding can be done by searching answers instead of questions and looking at the tags.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

the code looks a bit messy. Personally I would make it either an array lookup,

```
$card_trans = [
    "jcb"      => "JCB",
    "amex"     => "American Express",
    "diners"   => "Diners Club",
    "unionpay" => "UnionPay",
];
$card = $card_trans[$card] ?? ucfirst($card);
```

or a [match expression](https://www.php.net/match) available with PHP 8+:

```
$card = match ($card) {
    "jcb"      => "JCB",
    "amex"     => "American Express",
    "diners"   => "Diners Club",
    "unionpay" => "UnionPay",
    default    => ucfirst($card),
};
```

Comment: For the line `$card = $card_trans[$card] ?? ucfirst($card);`, I would change it to `$card = isset($card_trans[$card]) ? $card_trans[$card] : ucfirst($card);` or `$card = $card_trans[$card] ?: ucfirst($card);`, depending of your tolerance for warnings, if it is required to support older versions of PHP.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel At some point, you have to assume that people will be running a *vaguely* recent version of PHP. `??` was added in PHP 7.0; that was released in 2015, and [it's almost 4 years since either 7.0 or 5.6 received an official patch](https://www.php.net/eol.php). If your PHP is even older, you need to use `array( ... )` instead of `[ ... ]`, but it's probably a waste of time to say that every time we use the "new" syntax.

Comment: @IMSoP That's a perfectly fine argument. Except, no PHP version was specified anywhere. Therefore, we can't truly assume anything. There are systems still running PHP 5.4 to this day, as some web hosting companies still give support to it. Also, PHP 5.4 introduced the square bracket syntax. But still, that's a nice catch.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Indeed, but you have to draw the line somewhere - I wouldn't expect an answer to include caveats that objects in PHP 4 were pass-by-value, or that function definitions in PHP 2 (and 3?) used to have a syntax with no curly brackets. In my opinion, PHP 5.x is now old enough that anyone using it should be aware that most code samples they see won't just be copyable as-is.

Comment: @IMSoP I agree with you. I draw the line on "there are hosting servers that support 5.4" as just an afterthought. I wouldn't go any further down, as PHP 5.3 was when PHP started to be "modern". If written with care, any code written for PHP 5.4 can be used in PHP 8.1 without modifications. PHP 5.3 doesn't support `self` inside anonymous functions and the square brackets syntax, which will require to write the code a little too differently. Therefore, personally, I put the line in PHP 5.4.

Answer (score 7):

Using the array lookup, as YCS suggested, is a common convention to eliminate series of conditional statements. There are some other aspects of the code addressed below.

## Use descriptive variable names

A variable name like `$x` for a string is not very descriptive of what the string value typically holds. A name like `$card` or `$cardName` makes it easier for anyone reading the code (including your future self) to know what each variable represents.

## Consider using multiple variables

The variable `$x` is overwritten, though it may be useful to know the raw/original value later in the code. For this reason it may be wise to consider using a different variable for the updated name - e.g. `$formattedCard`.

## Use strict type comparisons

The conditional statements use loose equality operators - i.e. `==`. When the variable should usually be a string then strict equality comparison operators (e.g. `===`) can be used. [It is a good habit to use strict equality operators](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/126585/244085) whenever possible.